# linear independence of sums

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $ \left\{ v_i \right\}$ be linearly independent and suppose
>   $w\notin \operatorname{span} \left\{ v_i \right\}$. Prove $v_1\notin
>  \operatorname{span} \left\{ v_i+w \right\}$.

My attempt:

Suppose $v$ is in the latter span. Then there are scalars $\alpha_i$ satisfying $$v_1=\sum_i \alpha_i(v_i+w)=\sum_i\alpha_iv_i+w\sum_i\alpha_i$$ which means $$(\alpha_1-1)v_1+\sum_{i\geq 2}\alpha_iv_i=-(\sum_i\alpha_i)w.$$
$\sum_i\alpha_i\neq 0$ since otherwise $v_1=0$ which cannot be since $ \left\{ v_i \right\}$ is linearly independent. But then we're expressed $w$ as a linear combination of the $v_i$. Contradiction.

Is this okay?

Comment: Your proof is just fine :)

Comment: How do you justify "since otherwise $v_1=0$"? To me, the natural way to argue that $\sum_i \alpha_i \ne 0$ is to note that your second equation would then give a nontrivial linear relation for the linearly independent $\{v_i\}$. And indeed, right now your proof doesn't really use the necessary hypothesis that $\{v_i\}$ is linearly independent—only that $v_1\ne0$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slip when you conclude that $v_1=0$.

> If $\sum_i \alpha_i=0$, then $\alpha_1=1$ and $\alpha_i=0$ for $i>1$, by linear independence of $\{v_i\}$. This is a contradiction.

Once established that $\sum_i \alpha_i\ne0$, the argument is good.